# Email sent via custom button doesn't show under Activity history on lead

Tags: apex, visualforce

We have a VF custom button on lead record that sends details of lead via email to a selected contact but when the email is sent it doesn't shows up on lead activity history, is there any way to track the emails being sent through this button?

Apex class

```
/*Controller to send This lead to any selected Contact */

public class EmailController {
    public Lead leadRecord {get;set;}   
    public String TemplateID {get;set;}
    public String subject { get; set; }
    public String body { get; set; }
    public String htmlBody { get; set; }          
    public EmailTemplate  ET{ get; set; }
    public EmailController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        String lid = '';
        TemplateID = ''; 
        htmlBody ='';
        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') != null )
            lid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
         system.debug('lidid ' + lid );    

        try{             
            leadRecord = [select Status,ID,Contact__c,Name,Company,NumberOfEmployees,Street,City,State,PostalCode,Country,Website,Salutation,FirstName,
                         LastName,Title,Department__c,Email,Phone,MobilePhone,Fax,Product__c,Industry,Specialty__c,Rating,BuyingTimeframe__c,LeadSource,WebFormDetail__c,
                         Description,Marketing_Comments__c from Lead where id = : lid];
            //Change the Template name below.
            ET = [Select ID,HTMLValue,Subject from EmailTemplate  where   name = 'Lead Email' ];            
            if (ET != null){
                TemplateID  = ET.id;        
                htmlBody  = ET.HTMLValue ;
                Subject = ET.Subject;
                ReplaceTags();   
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,e.getMessage()));
        }
    }                  

    public void ReplaceTags(){

        if(htmlBody.indexOf('{!Lead.Id}') >-1)
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Lead.Id}',nullToString(leadRecord.Id));

        if(htmlBody.indexOf('{!Lead.Name}') >-1)
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Lead.Name}',nullToString(leadRecord.Name));

        if(htmlBody.indexOf('{!Lead.Company}') >-1)
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Lead.Company}',nullToString(leadRecord.Company));

        if(htmlBody.indexOf('{!Lead.NumberOfEmployees}') >-1)
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Lead.NumberOfEmployees}',nullToString(String.valueOf(leadRecord.NumberOfEmployees)));

        if(htmlBody.indexOf('{!Lead.Address}') >-1){
            String Address = '' ;
            Address =  Address  + nullToString(String.valueOf(leadRecord.Street));
            Address =  Address  + ' ' + nullToString(leadRecord.City);
            Address =  Address  + ','+ nullToString(leadRecord.State);
            Address =  Address  + ' ' + nullToString(leadRecord.PostalCode);
            Address =  Address  + ' ' + nullToString(leadRecord.Country);
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Lead.Address}',Address);

        }
        if(htmlBody.indexOf('{!Lead.Street}') >-1)
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Lead.Street}',nullToString(String.valueOf(leadRecord.Street)));

        if(htmlBody.indexOf('{!Lead.City}') >-1)
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Lead.City}',nullToString(leadRecord.City));

        if(htmlBody.indexOf('{!Lead.State}') >-1)
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Lead.State}',nullToString(leadRecord.State));

        if(htmlBody.indexOf('{!Lead.PostalCode}') >-1)
           htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Lead.PostalCode}',nullToString(leadRecord.PostalCode));

        if(htmlBody.indexOf('{!Lead.Country}') >-1)
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Lead.Country}',nullToString(leadRecord.Country));


        if(htmlBody.indexOf('{!Lead.FirstName} ') >-1)
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Lead.FirstName} ',nullToString(leadRecord.FirstName) );

        if(htmlBody.indexOf('{!Lead.LastName}') >-1)
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Lead.LastName}',nullToString(leadRecord.LastName));

        if(htmlBody.indexOf('{!Lead.Title}') >-1)
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Lead.Title}',nullToString(leadRecord.Title));


    }
    public PageReference send() {
     List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> email = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

        if(leadRecord.Contact__c == null){
             ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Please select contact and Try again.'));
             return null;   
        }

        if (TemplateID != null){
            // Query Contact Email ID
             try{
                Contact c =  [Select Id,Email,Name from Contact where ID =: leadRecord.Contact__c]; 
                if (c.Email != null && c.Email != ''){ 
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                        if(htmlBody.indexOf('{!Contact.Name}') >-1)
                            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Contact.Name}',nullToString(c.name));
                       String[] toAddresses = new String[] {c.email};
                        mail.setTargetObjectId(c.id);
                        mail.setSubject(Subject);
                        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                        mail.setHtmlBody(HtmlBody);
                        mail.setsaveAsActivity(true);
                        mail.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
                    //  mail.setTargetObjectId(LeadRecord.Id);                    
                    email.add(mail);
                    Messaging.sendEmail(email);
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Email sent successfully!'));

                    leadRecord.Status = 'Tracking';
                    update leadRecord;
                }
                else{
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Selected Contact has no Valid Email Address, kindly update the contact and Try again.'));
                    return null;   
                }
             }catch(Exception e){}
        }

        return new PageReference('/' + leadRecord.id);  
    }
    public String nullToString(String s){
        if (s== null)
            return '';
        else 
            return s;           
    }
    public PageReference cancel(){
        return new PageReference('/' + leadRecord.id);  
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Lead" extensions="EmailController" showheader="false">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Please select the Contact below">

            <br/>    
                <apex:pageMessages />
                <b><apex:outputLabel value="To" for="To"/>:</b><br /> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!leadRecord.Contact__c}" id="To" />
                <br />
                <br />                                
                <b><apex:outputLabel value="Subject" for="Subject"/>:</b><br />     
                <apex:outputText value="{!ET.subject}" id="Subject" />
                <br />
                <br />               
                <apex:inputTextArea value="{!htmlBody}" id="Body"  rows="30" cols="80" richText="true" disabled="true" /> 
                <br /><br /><br />
                <apex:commandButton value="Send Email" action="{!send}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel & Return" action="{!Cancel}" /> 
        </apex:pageBlock>     
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: If i comment the line // mail.setTargetObjectId(LeadRecord.Id); then the email is being sent to the contact i choose on lead record but it doesn't shows in activity history, if i don't comment it then it sends email to the email address on lead and it also tracks under activity history, not sure why it doesn't track when iam sending it to contact, something wrong

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @Admin_BA Glad to now it work for you. Now you can award the bounty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to use `saveAsActivity` to add this as activity.

```
mail.saveAsActivity(true);
```

This is the missing key here.

**Update:**
Use the `leadId` in `targetObject` Id to add in the Activity under lead and set the contact email address in to address to send email to contact.

```
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {usr.email};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
```

And in the end set the `mail.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);` so that your lead email will not get email.

Complete email code for reference

```
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {c.email};
   mail.setTargetObjectId(c.Id);
   mail.setSubject(Subject);
   mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
   mail.setHtmlBody(HtmlBody);
   mail.setsaveAsActivity(true);
   mail.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false)                    
   email.add(mail);
   Messaging.sendEmail(email);
```

Comment: Where exactly do i add it? if i add it below mail.setHtmlBody(HtmlBody);  then it's throwing me an error

Comment: You can add just after this `mail.setHtmlBody(HtmlBody);`  line.

Comment: @SarojBera so i added mail.setsaveAsActivity(true); but when i send email it still doesn't shows under lead activity history, any idea?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer that you have to supply "what id" as well along with `setSaveAsActivity` .

Comment: @SarojBera thanks for quick reply, do you know what i need to see in that brackets? i think i need to do something like lead.id but how do i query it? mail.setWhatId(??);

Comment: @SarojBera Bera I tried mail.setWhatId('{!Lead.Id}'); but again the email is not being sent at all

Comment: @Admin_BA You can not use Lead Id as it is not supported. As you are sending your email to Contact, you can set what id as `setWhatId( [select id from Account limit 1].id );`

Comment: @SarojBera Iam sending all lead details from lead record to a contact but the email only tracks in contact activity history and i want to show this email under lead record from where iam sending, i just tried your code and still it doesn't shows

Comment: @Admin_BA try to give leadId in targetObjectId. May be this will help in your use case.

Comment: @Admin_BA yes use `setTargetObjectId(lead.Id);` .

Comment: @TusharSharma Iam getting error when i use mail.setTargetObjectId(lead.Id); Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage].setTargetObjectId(Schema.SObjectField)

Comment: @SarojBera i tried mail.setTargetObjectId('{!Lead.Id}');  but again the email is not being sent at all

Comment: Don't use currly braces here. They are for vf. Give lid here and comment whatid and also use apex:pagemessage on page so that you get error notification

Comment: @TusharSharma if i use mail.setTargetObjectId(Lead.Id); then iam getting the error  Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage].setTargetObjectId(Schema.SObjectField)

Comment: @Admin_BA As per your code it should be `setTargetObjectId(leadRecord.Id);` not `setTargetObjectId(Lead.Id);`.

Comment: @SarojBera I tried that and i didn't see any error but when i test it, it's not sending any email

Comment: @Admin_BA What is the issue? Have you checked the debug and email logs? To get the email logs access Setup > Logs > Email Log Files.

Comment: When i add mail.setTargetObjectId(LeadRecord.Id); the email is not being sent at all and yes i checked the email logs and there is no email but when i remove that line from code then it sends an email but not being stored as activity under activity history

Comment: Here is what i have mail.setTargetObjectId(c.id);
                        mail.setSubject(Subject);
                        mail.setHtmlBody(HtmlBody); 
                        mail.setsaveAsActivity(true); 
                     // mail.setTargetObjectId(LeadRecord.Id);

Comment: @Admin_BA May be you have hit the daily org limit for this. Also if you are running this in SB then in setup> email deliverability > and set it to all emails.

Comment: This is in sandbox and we didn't hit daily org limit, i checked it and it is already set to All email

Comment: @TusharSharma Sorry i just checked the email is being sent but it's sending email to the email address on lead record, it's not sending to the person i select from button, if this gets fixed then my issue is solved, any idea?

Comment: @SarojBera If i comment the line // mail.setTargetObjectId(LeadRecord.Id); then the email is being sent to the contact i choose on lead record but it doesn't shows in activity history, if i don't comment it then it sends email to the email address on lead and it also tracks under activity history, not sure why it doesn't track when iam sending it to contact, something wrong

Comment: @Admin_BA you can try one thing.  Set to address and pass the contact email address there.  and set this ` message.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);`  so your target object Id will not get email.

Comment: @TusharSharma when i add mail.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false); it throws error Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage].setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(Boolean)

Comment: @Admin_BA I just test this in my org and working fine. Maye you are doing in some type. Check [reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40814/discussion-on-answer-by-tushar-sharma-email-sent-via-custom-button-doesnt-show).

Comment: @TusharSharma Iam getting error for the commented line, could you please let me know where exactly i need to update in my code above?

Comment: @Admin_BA check my updated answer.

Comment: @TusharSharma Iam getting compile error Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage].setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(Boolean) at line 156 column 25, i think if this is fixed then my issue is solved

Comment: I updated my apex class above in my question

Comment: @Admin_BA check your class version and set it to latest.

Comment: @TusharSharma Thank you so much that worked perfect

Answer (score 9):

You have to set `setSaveAsActivity` and `setWhatId`.

> Update

In your code, you have set `TargetObjectId` twice as `mail.setTargetObjectId(c.id);` and `mail.setTargetObjectId(LeadRecord.Id);`. Thats why when you comment  `mail.setTargetObjectId(LeadRecord.Id);` it is sent to Contact.

I was going through your code and **I believe your Lead does not have email address** and you are not logging the exception `catch(Exception e){}` anywhere. Can you

please update this line

`catch(Exception e){}`

with this new line

`catch(Exception e){System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());}`

and see what is the error message in debug log.

Comment: the lead does has email address and it's being sent to that email address and logging an activity but don't need to send this to lead, i need to send it to contact and should be able to log an activity